# Difficulties with installation script for hybris 5.6.02

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

The installation script reports a Build failure...

```
mlittle-mbook1:~ mlittle$ pwd

/Users/mlittle

mlittle-mbook1:~ mlittle$ cd hybris/bin/platform

mlittle-mbook1:platform mlittle$ ls -a

. .project build.number global.properties project.properties setantenv.sh tomcat

.. .settings build.xml hybrisserver.bat resources tcServer

.classpath adminserver.bat env.properties hybrisserver.sh roles.bat tenant_foo.properties

.externalToolBuilders adminserver.sh ext lib roles.sh tenant_junit.properties

.fbprefs apache-ant-1.9.1 extensions.xml license.bat ruleset.xml tenant_t1.properties

.pmd bootstrap extgen license.sh setantenv.bat tenant_t2.properties

mlittle-mbook1:platform mlittle$ . ./setantenv.sh

mlittle-mbook1:platform mlittle$ ant clean all

Buildfile: /Users/mlittle/hybris/bin/platform/build.xml

  [echo] /Users/mlittle/hybris/bin/platform/tomcat/bin

  [echo] /Users/mlittle/hybris/bin/platform/ext/core/web/webroot/WEB-INF/external-dependencies.xml was not found!
```

> BUILD FAILED
>
> It is looking for the path, and the file at that path..
>   Users/mlittle/hybris/bin/platform/ext/core/web/webroot/WEB-INF/external-dependencies.xml

When one looks in the path, I could not find Users/mlittle/hybris/bin/platform/ext/core/web/??

Any suggestions?

Best Regards.

====
Additional information... [2015-10-09-0952 EST]

Step:
Procedure:
MJL comment… 
1:Go to the Download page and download the packages you want to install.
:Done

2.:Create the directory where you will extract the ZIP archives. This directory must meet the following conditions:
It must be close to the system root directory (for example C:\hybris. You may download the files directly to the root directory, because the ZIP files already contain directory hybris). Microsoft Windows requires the directory paths to be shorter than 255 characters. Any part of a directory path exceeding this limitation is truncated. The hybris Commerce Suite modules installation creates several sub-directories, therefore use short directory paths.
Do not use directory paths containing spaces (such as C:\hybris Platform). Building the hybris Commerce Suite fails if the directory path contains spaces

:I have created a directory:

/00hybris/

3.:Extract the ZIP archives into the created directory. After the installation has been completed, the chosen directory should contain the structure similar to the example below:And unzipped the downloand file…

hybris-commerce-suite-5.6.0.2.zip into that path to get...

README
build-tools
hybris
hybris-Mobile-Apps-SDK
hybris-ems
hybris-oms
hybris-sbg
installer
licenses

And in the 00hybris/hybris path

bin

But Sebastian, I cannot find the 00hybris/hybris/config path after unzipping the download file…

4.:Set Up Apache Ant: 
To set up Apache Ant, perform the following steps:
1.  Open a command prompt in Microsoft Windows (shell in Unix family systems).
2.  Navigate to the ${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/platform directory, for example:C:\hybris\bin\platform.
3.  On Microsoft Windows systems, run the setantenv.bat file by entering setantenv.bat. Do not close the command window.
4.  On Unix-based systems (like Mac OS X or Linux), run setantenv.sh by entering . ./setantenv.sh. Do not close the command window.
5.  C:\hybris\bin\platform>setantenv.bat
6.  Setting ant home to: C:\hybris-5.0\hybris\bin\platform\apache-ant-1.8.2
7.  Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on March 26 2013

:With this..
a.  created a new shell session 
b.  Navigated to 00hybris/hybris/bin/platform…

mlittle-mbook1:hybris mlittle$ cd bin/platform
mlittle-mbook1:platform mlittle$ pwd.
-bash: pwd.: command not found
mlittle-mbook1:platform mlittle$ pwd
/Users/mlittle/00hybris/hybris/bin/platform
c. From /Users/mlittle/00hybris/hybris/bin/platform
, I ran, mlittle-mbook1:platform mlittle$ . ./setantenv.sh
 with the result…

mlittle-mbook1:platform mlittle$ . ./setantenv.sh
mlittle-mbook1:platform mlittle$

It appeared to run, but it gave back no response: why?

5:Perform Build Procedure for hybris Commerce Suite

Go to the Windows command prompt (shell in Unix family systems), navigate to the ${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/platform directory and type ant clean all.:See response below…

mlittle-mbook1:platform mlittle$ ant clean all
Buildfile: /Users/mlittle/00hybris/hybris/bin/platform/build.xml
     [echo] /Users/mlittle/00hybris/hybris/bin/platform/tomcat/bin
     [echo] /Users/mlittle/00hybris/hybris/bin/platform/ext/core/web/webroot/WEB-INF/external-dependencies.xml was not found!
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/mlittle/00hybris/hybris/log
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/mlittle/00hybris/hybris/data
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/mlittle/00hybris/hybris/temp/hybris
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/mlittle/00hybris/hybris/roles
    [input] 
    [input]  **** NO CONFIG FOLDER FOUND ****
    [input]
    [input]  No config folder was found at /Users/mlittle/00hybris/hybris/config.
    [input]  A "fresh" folder containing basic configuration files and the hybris 
    [input]  demo licence will be created for your convenience.
    [input]  Please adjust and review the configuration files (and license) and 
    [input]  call 'ant' again. This directory will never be overridden or 
    [input]  touched again. Always use this configuration folder for configuration 
    [input]  of platform, do not change anything within the platform folder.
    [input] 
    [input]  Please choose the configuration template. 
    [input]  Press [Enter] to use the default value ([develop], production)

```
 [copy] Copying 27 files to /Users/mlittle/00hybris/hybris/config
 [copy] Copying 1 file to /Users/mlittle/00hybris/hybris/config
```

BUILD FAILED
/Users/mlittle/00hybris/hybris/bin/platform/build.xml:20: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/mlittle/00hybris/hybris/bin/platform/resources/ant/antmacros.xml:123: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: de/hybris/ant/taskdefs/DbDriverValidator : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.defineClassFromData(AntClassLoader.java:1128)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.getClassFromStream(AntClassLoader.java:1299)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1354)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1315)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1068)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.addDefinition(Definer.java:579)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.execute(Definer.java:237)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:217)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:168)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ImportTask.importResource(ImportTask.java:230)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ImportTask.execute(ImportTask.java:162)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:179)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.configureProject(ProjectHelper.java:93)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:826)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Total time: 21 seconds
mlittle-mbook1:platform mlittle$

5: Continued 
Checking what this has done…
a.  it has created a directory structure under 00hybris/hybris:

bin
config
data
log
path.txt
path2.txt
roles
temp

And opening the 00Hybris/hybris/config/localextensions.xml file..

```
    <path dir="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}" />



    <!-- ext-platform-optional -->


    <!-- ext-incubator -->


    <!-- ext-commerce -->


    <!-- ext-backoffice -->


    <!-- ext-accelerator -->


    <!-- ext-cockpit -->


    <!-- ext-channel -->


    <!-- ext-addon -->


    <!-- ext-supportability -->


    <!-- ext-content -->


    <!-- ext-integration -->


    <!-- ext-print -->


    <!-- ext-template -->
    <extension name="yempty" />


    <!-- ext-atddtests -->


    <!-- ext-data -->


    <!-- ext-eventtracking -->


    <!-- ext-integration/sap/adtreco -->


    <!-- ext-integration/sap/asynchronousOM -->


    <!-- ext-integration/sap/availability -->


    <!-- ext-integration/sap/pointofsale -->


    <!-- ext-integration/sap/creditCheck -->


    <!-- ext-integration/sap/masterdata -->


    <!-- ext-integration/sap/core -->


    <!-- ext-integration/sap/testsupport -->


    <!-- ext-integration/sap/synchronousPricing -->


    <!-- ext-integration/sap/sapprodreco -->


    <!-- ext-integration/sap/productconfig -->


    <!-- ext-integration/sap/synchronousOM -->


</extensions>
```

It does not seem to have populated the variable with the value for ${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}... 00hybris/hybris/bin??

====
2015-10-10-1726EST

OK... investigated...

The problem is because there is an incompatibility between the version hybris was compiled and what is on my machine...

Comment: can you post your localextensions.xml file? Did you use the installer recipes to create the localextensions.xml? (If so, which one?) (the localextenions.xml file is in hybris/config 
Can you also post the exact exception/failure coming back from ant? (It usually gives hints and linenumbers as to where it fails)

Comment: Hello Sebastian, thank you... standby...

Comment: Hello Sebastian.. see my comments above... standby...

Comment: Hi Sebastian... see response above.. my thought is to manually edit my 00hybris/hybris/config/localextensions.xml, with the path for ${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}... 00hybris/hybris/bin?? However, when I ran . ./setantenv.sh it appears not to have ran correctly, as it did not respond as per the Hybris installation instructions... in which indicated that I should have a response indicating the Home path, but I did not get a response... why? How to fix?

Answer (score 6):

I think the root cause of the problem might be the wrong java version:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: de/hybris/ant/taskdefs/DbDriverValidator : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

indicates a java version conflict.

Hybris 5.6 should work with java, you can check at https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/System+Requirements+-+Release+5.6

Do you maybe have java 6 installed?
You can see via

```
java -version
```

To be sure you should use java 8 as per https://wiki.hybris.com/display/general/Third-Party+Compatibility+-+Release+5.6 
(btw, you can also signup for the https://experts.hybris.com/ forum to get more in-depth hybris answers)

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, standby... I have also put my questions to experts.hybris.com, but I have had no response! I am not impressed with the poor response on their internal forum, that is why I posted here, and I do appreciate your help...

From terminal.. 
mlittle-mbook1:~ mlittle$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)
mlittle-mbook1:~ mlittle$ 

But preferences,   indicates Java 8.. update 60, standby...

Comment: Weird, I have just downloaded and installed Java 8, Update 60, and re-ran java - version, but it is still indicating... java version "1.7.0_21"???? What gives... I shall restart my machine..

Comment: see comment above... problem with setting downloading, and setting java_home... !!

Comment: I have found there is a problem with my installation of the Java JDK on my MacBook, I have re-install Java 8, but there are problems with the Java_home, and Ant... I have posted an issue at [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062606/difficulties-with-updating-my-mac-to-the-latest-java-jdk ]

Comment: thank you, the problem was to do with the $java_home path.

Answer (score 2):

Hybris 5.6+ requires Java 8, update your environment variables to point Java 1.8

More references here:
http://hybrisdude.blogspot.com/2015/09/hybris-setup-issue-unsupported.html

Answer (score 1):

Found a post regarding this and it also helped to solve the issue :

[hybris installation issure resolved](http://webtech-kapil.blogspot.in/2015/10/hybris-installation-issue-563.html)