# Difficulties with updating my Mac to the latest Java JDK

Tags: java, ant

**[2015-10-12 12:51]**

> Running...

```
little-mbook1:platform mlittle$ ant clean all
     Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
       We cannot execute   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home//bin/java
```

> And running...

```
mlittle-mbook1:bin mlittle$ export   JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home
```

> I set java_home to:
>   JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home
>
> I have just noticed that Apache Ant is looking in the wrong path, with an additional ‘/'
>
> And according to your email
>
> “ Ant will try to use the file $JAVA_HOME/bin/java. If that doesn't exist, then > JAVA_HOME is not correct, it's that simple. If for example your java executable > is at /path/to/whatever/bin/java, then JAVA_HOME should be /path/to/whatever.”
>
> or… 
>       $JAVA_HOME/bin/java
>
> but the error message indicates that it is looking in the path..

```
$JAVA_HOME//bin/java
```

> **Notice the ‘//‘ instead of ‘/‘: how to correct this?**
>
> Or is there an ‘ant’ command, where I can force it to look in the correct path?

**=================**

[2015-10-12: 1204]

> Thank you, you have resolved one issue for me, I understand that /java is an executable in the path $java_home/bin/java, not a folder
>   As for $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version, 
>   I got the following...

```
mlittle-mbook1:~ mlittle$ /usr/libexec/java_home -v
java_home: option requires an argument -- v
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home
mlittle-mbook1:~ mlittle$ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

> Now re-running ant to attempt to build the hybris instance...

```
mlittle-mbook1:~ mlittle$ cd 00hybris/hybris/bin/platform
mlittle-mbook1:platform mlittle$ pwd
/Users/mlittle/00hybris/hybris/bin/platform
mlittle-mbook1:platform mlittle$ . ./setantenv.sh
mlittle-mbook1:platform mlittle$ ant clean all
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
We cannot execute   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home//bin/java
```

> As you can see, I am still having problems with 'ant' despite having what now appears the correct $java_home location.

## =======

=======

[2015-10-11-23:20]
FURTHER INVESTIGATION

```
mlittle-mbook1:Users mlittle$ cd   
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home

mlittle-mbook1:Home mlittle$ pwd
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home

mlittle-mbook1:Home mlittle$ ls -a
.                   README.html             db                  lib
..                  THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME-JAVAFX.txt  include         man
COPYRIGHT               THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt     javafx-src.zip release
LICENSE                 bin                 jre                 src.zip

mlittle-mbook1:Home mlittle$ cd bin

mlittle-mbook1:bin mlittle$ ls -a
.       jar     javafxpackager  jconsole    jjs     jsadebugd   keytool rmic servertool xjc
 ..     jarsigner   javah       jdb     jmap        jstack      native2ascii    rmid        tnameserv
appletviewer    java        javap       jdeps       jmc     jstat       orbd        rmiregistry unpack200
extcheck    javac       javapackager    jhat        jps     jstatd      pack200     schemagen   wsgen
idlj        javadoc     jcmd        jinfo       jrunscript  jvisualvm   policytool  serialver   wsimport

mlittle-mbook1:bin mlittle$ which java
/usr/bin/java
mlittle-mbook1:bin mlittle$ export    JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home
mlittle-mbook1:bin mlittle$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
mlittle-mbook1:bin mlittle$
```

====

```
 mlittle-mbook1:platform mlittle$ ant clean all
 Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
   We cannot execute   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home//bin/java
mlittle-mbook1:platform mlittle$*
```

==
INITIAL INVESTIGATION

I seem to have a problem with my Java installation on my MacBook, as this relates to the installation of a java based eCommerce platform [ [Difficulties with installation script for hybris 5.6.02](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33006794/difficulties-with-installation-script-for-hybris-5-6-02/33039004#33039004) ] and the use of Apache Ant...

1. Regarding my MacBook..
   System Software Overview:

> System Version:    OS X 10.10.5 (14F27)
>   Kernel Version: Darwin 14.5.0
>   Boot Volume:    Macintosh HD
>   Boot Mode:  Normal
>   Computer Name:  mlittle-mbook1
>   User Name:  mlittle-mbook1 (mlittle)
>   Secure Virtual Memory:  Enabled
>   Time since boot:    1 day5:34

=========

**1. Checked which java…**

```
mlittle-mbook1:~ mlittle$ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

**2. Recheck which Java..**

```
mlittle-mbook1:~ mlittle$ ls -l `which java`
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  74  5 Nov  2014 /usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java
```

**3. I then downloaded the JDK version 8, update 60, and so in the path:**

/Library/Java/Java?JavaVirtualMachines

Previously it had..

> /jdk1.7.0_21.jdk

Now It has

> /jdk1.7.0_21.jdk
>   /jdk1.8.0_60.jdk

This is confusing, I was expecting that it would replace  /jdk1.7.0_21.jdk
 with  /jdk1.8.0_60.jdk

**4. I check the version of java..**

```
mlittle-mbook1:~ mlittle$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_21"
mlittle-mbook1:~ mlittle$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)
```

It was still indicating java version “1.7.0_21"???

And so I renamed /jdk1.7.0_21.jdk to /old-jdk1.7.0_21.jdk

**4. I again check the version of java, and then I got…**

```
mlittle-mbook1:~ mlittle$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
```

**5. Which should be the correct version of Java for Hybris5.6.0.2 [this the java based eCommerce platform that I am trying to install] by setting the ANT environment variables, and commence the build process [ant clean all]… but…**

```
mlittle-mbook1:platform mlittle$ . ./setantenv.sh
```

Tried to ant clean all.. and got an error message relating to JAVA_HOME

```
mlittle-mbook1:platform mlittle$ ant clean all
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home//bin/java
```

**6. Again checked the java path…**

```
mlittle-mbook1:platform mlittle$ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

**7. I tried to change the Java_home path and then re-run ANT.**.

```
mlittle-mbook1:platform mlittle$ export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home
mlittle-mbook1:platform mlittle$ ant clean all
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /Library/Java/Home/bin/java
```

**8. Again checked “which Java”**

```
mlittle-mbook1:platform mlittle$ which java
/usr/bin/java
mlittle-mbook1:platform mlittle$ $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version
-bash: /Library/Java/Home/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

**9.I tried to change the Java_home, reran Ant, but still got an error message..**

```
mlittle-mbook1:platform mlittle$ export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
mlittle-mbook1:platform mlittle$ ant clean all
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines//bin/java
```

**10. 9.I tried to change the Java_home, reran Ant, but still got an error message..**

```
mlittle-mbook1:platform mlittle$ export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
mlittle-mbook1:platform mlittle$ ant clean all
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/bin/java
```

**11. Again checked which java**

```
mlittle-mbook1:platform mlittle$ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

I am confused, clearly I do not have my java set home variables set up properly: any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this should be the correct one:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Ant will try to use the file `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java`. If that doesn't exist, then `JAVA_HOME` is not correct, it's that simple.
If for example your `java` executable is at `/path/to/whatever/bin/java`, then `JAVA_HOME` should be `/path/to/whatever`.

Comment: Hello you are right, it is looking for the executables at 

$JAVA_HOME/bin/java,  

and the $JAVA_HOME is now point to..

JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home, 

but the real problem is from above the executables are all located at 

$JAVA_HOME/bin/, 

but there is  no /java sub-directory…

should I hack one ‘/java', and copy the executables from /bin to /bin/java??

Comment: No. `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home` looks correct. `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java` is a file, not a directory. That's the executable. At this point, your Ant should work, with the `JAVA_HOME` value as in my post. Do you still get an error? If yes, then please edit into your question the output, and also the output of `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version`

Comment: @FlashJackFromGundagai so how's it going?

Comment: thanks for the help, I really do appreciate your help.. I have ran the output of $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version, and then attempted to run 'ant', but it ['ant'] is still giving me an error message... see above...

Comment: In your last output, in the error message of ant, where you see the //, the path is JDK 7 and not 8. Look closely. Btw, having // in the path is no problem at all. Can you please clean up your question? Don't you see that it's really messy and hard to read? We can surely figure your problem out, but we need to keep the facts clean, and approach the problem in a structured, clean way, identifying and eliminating each subproblem piece by piece. It takes patience and discipline. Slow down, take a step back, think clear

Comment: got it!!! Thanks for your help...  problem was java_home was somehow still pointing to the old java JDK.. re-ran... export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home , and re-ran 'Ant Clean All', and it has completed the build step..

Comment: Awesome you could figure it out :)